# Inno Setup Compiler: How to use a constant from Setup region within a event method

Tags: inno-setup

within the `inno setup compiler` there are regions like:

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={pf}\cow1


function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ExecInfo: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    ExecInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(ExecInfo);
    ExecInfo.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ExecInfo.Wnd := 0;
    ExecInfo.lpFile := DefaultDirName + '\{#Exewampmanager}';
    ExecInfo.nShow := SW_HIDE;

    if ShellExecuteEx(ExecInfo) then
    begin
      if WaitForSingleObject(ExecInfo.hProcess, 3000) = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
      begin
        TerminateProcess(ExecInfo.hProcess, 666);
        MsgBox('You just killed a little kitty!', mbError, MB_OK);
      end
      else
        MsgBox('The process was terminated in time!', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

how can i use the `DefaultDirName` const from the [Setup] region, within the function?

ps:

`ExecInfo.lpFile := DefaultDirName + '\{#Exewampmanager}';` does not work

Comment: `ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\{#Exewampmanager}'` - In the script `DefaultDirName` becomes `{app}` constant. You can use it as above.

Comment: now this, should work

Comment: `ExecInfo.lpFile := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\{#Exewampmanager};` should work fine.

Comment: OT: you will kill that wamp after 3 seconds if it doesn't terminate till that time.  You know that, right ?

Comment: Please don't tag inno-setup questions with "windows installer".  The two technologies are unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must expand the constant, like:

```
ExpandConstant('{app}\myapp.exe')
```

where `{app}` is the final destination folder